# Unable to get value from scope using directive

Tags: angularjs

```
<check_address address-id='address.addressId'></check_address> // html

app.directive('checkAddress', ['ajaxFactory', function (ajaxFactory) {
   return {
      restrict : 'EA',
      scope:{
        addressId : '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'address.html',  
      link: function (scope, elt ,attrs) {
    console.log(scope.addressId);
      }
     };
}]);
```

Unable to get scope.addressId. It is showing undefined. But my value is present in scope. If anyone know means please update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi you posted code is ok please see here http://jsbin.com/coqawa/1/edit?html,js,console check other parts 'ajaxfactory' or your template

Comment: Is it required that `scope.addressId` should be two-way?

Comment: Have you checked whether address.addressId is having value. You can use Batarang chrome extension and try to debug from browser console itself and check the scope contain address.addressId defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myId: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

      iAttrs.$observe('myId', function(value){
        alert(value);
      });      
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you add some explanatory text?

Comment: // I can able to see the addressId in console while using console.log(scope);
//If am trying to use console.log(scope.addressId) means I can't fetch addressId value.